# I just accepted a "come back to us" type offer $100 Adwords Credit - Now 80% of my Adsense Ads are for Google Adwords

Tags: google, google-adsense, advertising, google-ads

I don't know if this is related, and I haven't been able to find any information on it anywhere. I just accepted a $100 Adwords credit offer from Google. Shortly after I did that, roughly 80% of the ads I have placed on my site are ads for Google Adwords. Completely irrelevant to my site and its content.

Is it possible the two are related? My sites have been displaying relevant content for years now, why the change? Any feedback on this would be appreciated... Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like the two are related. Google have likely dropped a cookie on your computer that recognises that you've visited the AdWords site. Clear your cookies and see if the issue continues.

The good news is that this behaviour is probably just targetting you, and not your site's general audience.